# SVD package installation failure after using Revolution R

Tags: r, package, svd, revolution-r

I have recently installed Revolution R (3.2.1). Now, when I am trying to install the svd package from source but I see the following error message.

```
> install.packages('svd',type='source')
Installing package into ‘/home/guest/sng8/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2015-07-01/src/contrib/svd_0.3.3-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 84147 bytes (82 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 82 KB

Multithreaded BLAS/LAPACK libraries detected. Using 6 cores for math algorithms.
* installing *source* package ‘svd’ ...
** package ‘svd’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

<..I am deleting few unnecessary details here>

** testing if installed package can be loaded
Multithreaded BLAS/LAPACK libraries detected. Using 6 cores for math algorithms.
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
unable to load shared object '/home/guest/sng8/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.2/svd/libs/svd.so':
/home/guest/sng8/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.2/svd/libs/svd.so: undefined symbol: lsame_
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/guest/sng8/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.2/svd’
* restoring previous ‘/home/guest/sng8/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.2/svd’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘svd’ had non-zero exit status
```

I don't need it directly. I use Rssa package which depends on this SVD package. It used to work just fine before with regular R 3.2.1. I have also tried to install it from github but I keep getting same error. I am also attaching the sessionInfo details.

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
[4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
[7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RevoUtilsMath_3.2.1
```

Has anyone else faced similar behavior or something similar? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That really is the sort of question you should be asking Revolution R Enterprise support.

Comment: @DerekMcCraeNorton: sure! I will go ahead and ask at their support as well. I just thought if there is any change I could make in SVD package layer to make it working which is more of a R-stat related question.